# PHP: global variable not being stored?

Tags: php, global-variables

It turns out this has nothing to do with global variables (sorry discussed in another post).

I was trying to keep all the code on one page (self-processing), but I'm pretty sure it's not possible. Arranging the following code outlined in the answer below, on the same page, does not work. Figures.

*edited to add the whole script minus the CSS (unnecessary).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Inventory Tables</title>
    </head>
<style></style>
<body>
<?php //IRCinventoryhome.php
    require("IRCpage.inc");
    require_once 'IRCinventoryconfig.php';

    $homepage = new IRCtemplate();

    $homepage->Display();

    session_start();
?>

<!-- Dropdown Menu for Table Selection -->

    <div id="contentHeader">
        <?php //Menu for table selection
        ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
            if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

        $result = $connection->query("SHOW TABLES");

        $table = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
            $table[] = $row[0];
            }
        $count = count($table);
        ?>

    <div id="select">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <select name="value">
                <?php for ($pointer = 0 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) {
                    echo <<<_END
                        <pre>
                            <option value="$table[$pointer]">$table[$pointer]</option>
                        </pre>
_END;
                }
?>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" value="go">
        </form>
    </div> <!-- End .select -->
    </div> <!-- End #contentHeader -->
<div id="content">


<!-- Code for Database Tables and Actions -->

<?php //inventory mysql tables
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST['value'])) {

$thisTable = $_POST['value'];

global $thisTable;

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);

$queryColumns  = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $thisTable";
$resultColumns = $connection->query($queryColumns);
    if (!$resultColumns) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);

$columns = array();
    while ($column = $resultColumns->fetch_row()){
        $columns[] = $column[0];
     }

echo "<div id=\"table\"><table class=\"CSSTableGenerator\" >\n";
$count = count($columns);

$insertColumns = array();
for ($pointer = 1 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) {
    $insertColumns[] = $columns[$pointer];
    }


for ($pointer = 0 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) {
    echo "<th scope=\"col\" bgcolor=\"#efefef\">";
    echo $columns[$pointer];
    echo "</th>";
    }
    echo "<th>ACTIONS</td>";
$queryRows  = "SELECT * FROM $thisTable";
    $resultRows = $connection->query($queryRows);
    if (!$resultRows) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);

$rows = $resultRows->num_rows;


for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
    {
        $resultRows->data_seek($j);
        $row = $resultRows->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        $count = count($row);

        echo "<tr>";
        for ($pointer = 0 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) {
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row[$pointer];
            echo "</td>";
        }
?>
        <td>
            <input action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" type="submit" value="edit" name="edit">
            <input action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" type="submit" value="delete" name="delete">
        </td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
echo "</table></div>"; //end table, end content

$connection->close();
}
?>

<!-- FORM FOR ADDING ROWS TO CURRENT TABLE -->

<div id="table">
    <table id="formTable">
        <form name="addRow" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="control">
            <td>
                Add row?
            </td>
        <?php for ($pointer = 1 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) { ?>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="<?php echo $columns[$pointer];?>">
            </td>
        <?php } ?>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="go">
            </td>
        </form>
    </table>
</div> <!-- end form, end table, end content -->
<?php

global $thisTable;
echo $thisTable;

if (isset($_POST['control'])) {

global $thisTable;
echo $thisTable;

$valuesArray = array();
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $valuesArray = $_POST;
    }

$columnsArray = array_keys($valuesArray);
//array_splice($columnsArray, 0, 1);

$columnsString = implode(", ", $columnsArray);

print_r($columnsString);

$insertValues = array();
foreach($valuesArray as $values) {
     $insertValues[] = $values;
    }

$valuesString = implode(" ", $insertValues);
$valuesString = "'".$valuesString."'";
$valuesString = str_replace(" ", "', '", $valuesString);
$valuesString = substr($valuesString, 3);

print_r($valuesString);
/*
$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
            if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);


    $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO $thisTable ($columnsString) VALUES ($valuesString)";                           
    $result      = $connection->query($queryInsert);

    if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
      $connection->error . "<br><br>";


$connection->close();
*/
}
?>
</div> <!-- End #content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to "import" a global variable inside an `if` loop, only inside functions where it would otherwise be out of scope; but it's not recommended to pollute the global space with global variables anyway

Comment: Without more context, there is nothing here that could go wrong. Plese post the surrounding code for both of these. Calling `global` in the top example doesn't "make it global", but if it is already in the global scope it already will be.

Comment: I guess your problem is that in your second if loop the global variable that you are trying to get is not defined in the global scope. It exists only in your first if loop. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Two things; ok so *technically* you're missing a closing brace. Second, does your 2nd POST contain a name attribute for that one too? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski Okay, I've added the entire script.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey Fred, can you explain name attribute?

Comment: I don't see a closing `</select>` tag for `<select name="value">`. As for the name attribute; it's ok, you have it. But there's no value set for the hidden one, whether it makes a difference or not. Another thing `<option name....` - `<option>` doesn't have name attributes, only `<select>` should have one.

Comment: Then you have `<input action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" type="submit" value="edit" name="edit">
            <input action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" type="submit" value="delete" name="delete">` which are outside your form tags.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I will fix the select now... As for the two buttons, technically they don't do anything yet. Just there to serve as place holders for the moment.

Comment: Also, error reporting does not yield any useful information.

Comment: Far as I could test, your `global $thisTable;` inside your conditional `if (isset($_POST['control']))` will only be set if the accompanying submit `<input type="submit" value="go">` for it is pressed.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- That's what's weird about it, after I click the go button, print_r($columnsString) and print_r($valuesString) return the correct information, but echo/print_r $thisTable returns nothing, which I assume means it's null. I just can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Confirmed, var_dump($thisTable) inside (isset($_POST['control'])) { returns null.

Comment: You have more than one form, and `$thisTable = $_POST['value'];` is declaring `$thisTable` to be global. I think you're losing the variable scope. Why not just make it global whether the form(s) is submitted or not?

Comment: @ Fred -ii- It must be. I was hoping to avoid making any major changes to the code, but I think I'm going to have to rewrite it. As it stands, I have to submit the first form in order create the table variable (how the particular table is determined). Then I need to the second form to submit the values for each row (which requires the table name for executing the insert query). Thanks for talking this through with me...

Comment: You're welcome. Another thing you can try in keeping your present code, are sessions. It's worth a shot.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I appreciate the suggestion, but alas have already been that route. It resulted in an error which unfortunately I can't recall. In all likelihood I'll try again before committing to any major changes, but I'm going to get some rest first. I'll post an update if I can resolve the issue.

Comment: Things are often best left to getting some rest. Many a time and after sleeping on it, will result in success. It works every time for me. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred -ii- Indeed. Using session variables I am still getting the same problem. After submitting the second form my session variable becomes NULL. The only solution I've found involves modifying the php.ini file. However, it involves me giving folder access to the web server, which seems like more trouble than necessary at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 20 hours or so I'm still not sure if this possible to do all on the same page. But this solution works...

Page one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Interactive Resource Center Inventory</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
<script src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('input[type=submit]')
        prop('disabled',true);
    });//end submit
    var max_fields      = 4; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div>Column: <input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});//end ready
</script>
<style>

#table {
    margin-top:2px;
    }

#formTable {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;padding:0px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    }

#formTable td{
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
    }

#formTable input[type="text"]{
        width:95%;
        }

.CSSTableGenerator {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%; 
border:1px solid #000000;
border-top:none;
border-right:none;
border-left:none;
}

.CSSTableGenerator table{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;padding:0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#e5e5e5; }
.CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#ffffff; }

.CSSTableGenerator th{
border:1px solid #000000;
border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
width:100px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator td{
vertical-align:middle;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
text-align:left;
padding:7px;
width:100px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:normal;
color:#000000;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td{
border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td{
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #cccccc), color-stop(1, #b2b2b2) );    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100% );    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#cccccc", endColorstr="#b2b2b2");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#cccccc,b2b2b2);
background-color:#cccccc;
border:0px solid #000000;
text-align:center;
border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
margin-top:-2px;
</style>
<body>
<?php //IRCinventoryhome.php
require("IRCpage.inc");
require("IRCinventoryfunctions.php");
require_once 'IRCinventoryconfig.php';

$homepage = new IRCtemplate();

$homepage->Display();

session_start();
    $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];
    $thisTable = $_SESSION['value'];
    var_dump($_SESSION);

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);
    global $connection;

$result = $connection->query("SHOW TABLES");

$table = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    $table[] = $row[0];
    }
$count = count($table);

?>

<!-- Dropdown Menu for Table Selection -->

<div id="contentHeader">
    <div id="select">
        <form action="http://localhost:8888/IRC/IRCinventoryhometest.php" method="POST">
            <select name="value">
                <?php for ($pointer = 0 ; $pointer < $count ; ++$pointer) {
                    echo <<<_END
                        <pre>
                            <option value="$table[$pointer]">$table[$pointer]</option>
                        </pre>
_END;
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="go">
        </form>
    </div> <!-- End .select -->
</div> <!-- End #contentHeader -->

<div id="content">

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
$thisTable = "OUTGOING";

$queryColumns  = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $thisTable";
$resultColumns = $connection->query($queryColumns);
    if (!$resultColumns) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);
global $resultColumns;

$queryRows  = "SELECT * FROM $thisTable";
    $resultRows = $connection->query($queryRows);
    if (!$resultRows) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);
global $resultRows;

$rows = $resultRows->num_rows;
global $rows;

global $connection;

drawTable();

$connection->close();
} else {

if(isset($_POST['value'])) {
    $thisTable = $_POST['value'];
    }

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);
    if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);
    global $connection;


$queryColumns  = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $thisTable";
$resultColumns = $connection->query($queryColumns);
    if (!$resultColumns) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);
global $resultColumns;

$queryRows  = "SELECT * FROM $thisTable";
    $resultRows = $connection->query($queryRows);
    if (!$resultRows) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);
global $resultRows;

$rows = $resultRows->num_rows;
global $rows;

global $connection;

drawTable();

?>
<!-- FORM FOR ADDING ROWS TO CURRENT TABLE -->

<div id="table">
    <table id="formTable">
        <form name="addRow" action="http://localhost:8888/IRC/IRCprocessinventory.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="control">
            <td>
                Add row?
            </td>
            <td></td>
        <?php for ($pointer = 2 ; $pointer < $countColumnsGlobal ; ++$pointer) { ?>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="<?php echo $columns[$pointer];?>">
            </td>
        <?php } ?>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </form>
    </table>
</div> <!-- end table -->
<?php 
}

?>
</div> <!-- End #content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
require_once 'IRCinventoryconfig.php';

ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['value'])) { 
    $thisTable = $_SESSION['value'];

    $valuesArray = array();
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $valuesArray = $_POST;
        }

    $columnsArray = array_keys($valuesArray);
    array_splice($columnsArray, 0, 1);

    $columnsString = implode(", ", $columnsArray);


    $insertValues = array();
    foreach($valuesArray as $values) {
        $insertValues[] = $values;
        }

    $valuesString = implode("','", $insertValues);
    $valuesString = "'".$valuesString."'";
    $valuesString = substr($valuesString, 3);

    $connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);
        if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

    $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO $thisTable ($columnsString) VALUES ($valuesString)";                           
    $result      = $connection->query($queryInsert);

    if (!$result) echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
        $connection->error . "<br><br>";
    else echo "Successful entry";

    $connection->close();

}
?>
```